# How to transform XML data files adding structural tags using Java API

Tags: java, dom

I have an XML like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><root>
<parameters>
<param>
        <name>john</name>
        <age>18</age>
</param>
</parameters>
```

and would want to transform it like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><root>
<parameters>
<L1>
    <param>
        <name>john</name>
        <age>18</age>
    </param>
</L1>   
</parameters>
```

programmatically using DOM Java APIs to enclose the  tags

Comment: Is this `<root>` tag an error?

Comment: yes Maurice,  there is a ending </root> tag

primarily am trying to nest the XML fragment under enclosing tag <L1> here

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it programmatically, you can do this:

```
        // load document
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(url.toURI().toString());

        // Transform document
        Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
        Element elm = doc.createElement("L1");
        while (root.hasChildNodes()) {
            Node child = root.getFirstChild();
            root.removeChild(child);
            elm.appendChild(child);
        }
        root.appendChild(elm);

        // Output to console for testing
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
        transformer.transform(source, result);
```

But you could rather use an XSLT stylesheet (you're using a transformer anyway).